# Is middleware a NodeJS or ExpressJS (or similar) concept?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I keep seeing questions to explain the middleware concept in NodeJS, and it always seems to me that they're poorly formulated. Do people always mean ExpressJS middleware, or there is a practice to use this concept in pure NodeJS?

I checked different abstract explanations [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/middleware/what-is-middleware) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) among others, and I definitely understand, that the concept exists beyond either NodeJS and Express. I'm rather curious if NodeJS middleware is always understood as the one implemented by Express or another library, or NodeJS in itself has the concept built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, middleware doesn't exist in pure Node.js (at least at the way we're used to seeing them), this concept came to Node.js with Express.js. But nobody forbids you to write your own implementation in Node.js, you need to start with the next function, which is responsible for all middleware. The point of this function is that it should be called at the very end and either terminate the process or pass objects req/res to the next middlewares. The implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/router/index.js#L176).

Comment: was my understanding as well

Answer (score 1):

The middleware mentioned in your references isn't the same category as nodejs / express middleware.

In express, middleware is the name (a bombastic name in my opinion) for Javascript functions with this signature.

```
function mWare (req, res, next) {
  /* do something useful with req and res */
  next()
}
```

These express middleware functions are invoked, by the express framework, typically before the `.get()` or other function handling each specific request. **This concept of middleware comes from the express framework, not from nodejs itself.**

Other web frameworks built on nodejs have other ways of intercepting requests. For example, hapi uses server extension points.

The middleware mentioned in your references is not the same thing at all. It is made of larger components. Queuing, load balancing, database access, logging and caching systems are all examples of that kind of middleware. You could make the case that your entire express / nodejs / Linux server is middleware by that definition. An nginx reverse-proxy server sitting between your nodejs program and the network is definitely that sort of middleware.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm not sure though if it actually answers my question. I'll quote it, so it might clarify what I mean better - "I definitely understand, that the concept exists beyond either NodeJS and Express. I'm rather curious if NodeJS middleware is always understood as the one implemented by Express or another library, or NodeJS in itself has the concept built-in."